# Keep alarmmanager when app gets closed

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, taskmanager

Well i have searched about 5 hours but no answer seems to do the trick. My app will keep tracking postal objects from a website, and needs to make a refresh every X (user defines it) amount of time to check for updates on the site, so the user *will be aware of it* and even can turn this feature off if he wants (i will cancel the alarmmanagers manually if so).

What I need to do is something like whatsapp, facebook or gmail, that checks for messages even with the app closed, and send user some notification. But that just seems impossible... I checked with "adb shell dumpsys alarm" and the alarm is there, but only while the app is running. I know this is the exactly expected thing to happen, but how does these other apps always set their AlarmMannagers againd when app is closed?

My current code:

**Manifest**:

```
<service android:name="services.HelloService"
        android:process=":remote"/>

    <receiver android:name="entidade.NotificationPublisher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="IWillStartAuto" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**HelloService**:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    System.out.println("Hello Service Starting...");
    ArrayList<Objeto> list = new ObjetoDAO(this).getAllObjetos(); //Sets the alarms...
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            if(!list.get(i).isArquivado())
                list.get(i).setAlarme(this);
        }
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    System.out.println("Hello Service Ending...");
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("IWillStartAuto"));
}
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("IWillStartAuto"));
}
```

**NotificationPublisher**:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<Objeto> lista = new ObjetoDAO(context).getAllObjetos(); //list of tracked objects
    for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++){ 
        if(!lista.get(i).isArquivado()) //sets the AlarmMannager if users want it...
            lista.get(i).testeNotificacao(context);
    }
}}
```

**UPDATE:** Code used to set the alarm...
**AlarmManager:**

```
public void setAlarme(Context context) {
    if (!isArquivado()) {
        int idDoAlarme = getId();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long interval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idDoAlarme, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Also noted something: tested the app on my old phone (LG E435f, with Android 4.1.2) and surprise, the Alarm is still set after the app gets closed. So, could it be something with my phone (Lenovo K5 A6020l36, with Android 5.1.1)? But in this case, how are whatsapp and gmail still running their alarms on this phone with the apps closed?

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your question that you want to send notification from server to your user like whats-app, Facebook, etc. even when app is closed.
Have you read about **Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)** or **Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)**, I think this would more suit to your problem. Click [Here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to know more about it.

Comment: Well, maybe i didn't express myself as i wished... No notification from server needed, just a pushnotification... Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up your `AlarmManager` to fire at your predetermined date\time.
2. When it fires, your code will run so just repeat step 1 to set up the next time you want it to fire and then perform whatever functions you need to in order to check your site (start a service that does this)
3. Repeat from step 2

Don't forget that alarms do not survive a reboot of the device so you will need to set it up again if the device restarts.

Comment: I did this too... but as soon as I close the app (slide it away from "task switcher", for example), all the AlarmManager are cancelled... :(

Comment: I am not aware of any function of AlarmManager that automatically cancels alarms if the task exits and this has never happened in any alarm I have ever set. You would need to post your alarm code as none of the code you have posted seems to relate to your question.

Comment: OK, put the code on the update (by the way, thanks for the attention!)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the user kills your app, than it depends on the manofacturer. Some kill only the process, others kill the process along with services, broadcasts, alarmmangers (etc.) associated with the process.

Maybe the GCM can survive this kill process, as you sayd that whatsapp does get its notifications...